# Scratch defection detection in a random background

Tags: c++, image, opencv, detection, halcon

normaly when scratch exist product surface, the value of pixes are different from its background, but when background like random noise it's difficult distinguish scratch defect from background.

[src img include scrach cross](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNo2Z.png)
[binaryed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU3S5.png)

one common method seperate differen gray value is binalization, the src image and binalized img, the result is difficult to seperate scratch.

```
Mat img_roi = imread(str_path_read, 0);
/*fix threshold*/
int thresh_b = 170;
Mat img_roi_b;
threshold(img_roi, img_roi_b, thresh_b, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

Comment: Have you considered using a line detection algorithm (like a Hough transformation) to detect the scratches? https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html

Comment: it's a method, i will have a try, thx!